# How to move folders to other folders by grouping them according to a keyword present in the folder name?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, batch-processing

To move *files* into their relative folders ordered by key string in file like this

[Example script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWL0D.png)

I use this script

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "SPLITCHAR=-"  & rem // (a single character to split the file names)
set "SEARCHSTR=_"  & rem // (a certain string to be replaced by another)
set "REPLACSTR= "  & rem // (a string to replace all found search strings)
set "OVERWRITE="   & rem // (set to non-empty value to force overwriting)

rem // Get file location and pattern from command line arguments:
set "LOCATION=%~1" & rem // (directory to move the processed files into)
set "PATTERNS=%~2" & rem // (file pattern; match all files if empty)

rem /* Prepare overwrite flag (if defined, set to character forbidden
rem    in file names; this affects later check for file existence): */
if defined OVERWRITE set "OVERWRITE=|"
rem // Continue only if target location is given:
if defined LOCATION (
    rem // Create target location (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%LOCATION%"
    rem /* Loop through all files matching the given pattern
    rem    in the current working directory: */
    for /F "eol=| delims=" %%F in ('dir /B "%PATTERNS%"') do (
        rem // Process each file in a sub-routine:
        call :PROCESS "%%F" "%LOCATION%" "%SPLITCHAR%" "%SEARCHSTR%" "%REPLACSTR%"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
rem // Retrieve first argument of sub-routine:
set "FILE=%~1"
rem // Split name at (first) split character and get portion in front:
for /F "delims=%~3" %%E in ("%~1") do (
    rem // Append a split character to partial name:
    set "FOLDER=%%E%~3"
)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Right-trim partial name:
if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4%~3=!"
set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~3=!"
rem /* Check whether partial name is not empty
rem    (could happen if name began with split character): */
if defined FOLDER (
    rem // Replace every search string with another:
    if not "%~4"=="" set "FOLDER=!FOLDER:%~4=%~5!"
    rem // Create sub-directory (surpress error if it already exists):
    2> nul md "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    rem /* Check if target file already exists; if overwrite flag is
    rem    set (to an invalid character), the target cannot exist: */
    if not exist "%~2\!FOLDER!\!FILE!%OVERWRITE%" (
        rem // Move file finally (surpress `1 file(s) moved.` message):
        1> nul move /Y "!FILE!" "%~2\!FOLDER!"
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

But i wish to do a similar thing for folders and not for files.
For example, I have these *folders* list

```
Absolute Moebius - Volume 2 - The Long Tomorrow
Absolute Moebius - Volume 3
Agenzia X - Volume 1 - La Recluta
Agenzia X - Volume 2 - Black Point
Agenzia X - Volume 3 - Soli
Akira - Volume 10
Akira - Volume 20
Akira - Volume 23
Alan Ford - Volume 11 - Il Numero Uno
Alan Ford - Volume 12 - La Triste Storia Di Un Giovane Ricco
Alan Ford - Volume 13 - Golf
```

and i wish to move them into a folder structure like that

```
Absolute Moebius [folder]
|
|---> Absolute Moebius - Volume 2 - The Long Tomorrow  
|---> Absolute Moebius - Volume 3 
|
|
Agenzia X  [folder]
|
|---> Agenzia X - Volume 1 - La Recluta 
|---> Agenzia X - Volume 2 - Black Point  
|---> Agenzia X - Volume 3 - Soli  
|
Akira [folder]
|
|---> Akira - Volume 10
|---> Akira - Volume 20
|---> Akira - Volume 23
|
.
.
:
```

Usually many folder names contains `Volume` , `volume` , or some other key word that is repeated and that could be used as a discriminant

Edit: question ask how you can move folders and not files. For example, script above works when you moving *files* grouping them inside folders: you can see an example [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWL0D.png). But I wish to move ***folders*** and not files for grouping them inside other folders using, for example, a keyword like criteria, for example `Volume` word

I add also Powershell tag because for me is good also a powershell script

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: question ask how you can move folders and not files. For example, script above works when you moving *files* grouping them inside folders: you can see an example [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWL0D.png). But I wish to move ***folders*** and not files for grouping them inside other folders using, for example, a keyword like criteria, for example `Volume` word

Comment: If you wanna group your folders you'll need a distinct word that identifies each group. From what you're saying, all folders have the word `Volume`. First you need to identify what can be used to group them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have selected an answer. Here is another way.

```
# Setup test data
$Dirs = @(
    'Absolute Moebius - Volume 2 - The Long Tomorrow'
    ,'Absolute Moebius - Volume 3'
    ,'Agenzia X - Volume 1 - La Recluta'
    ,'Agenzia X - Volume 2 - Black Point'
    ,'Agenzia X - Volume 3 - Soli'
    ,'Akira - Volume 10'
    ,'Akira - Volume 20'
    ,'Akira - Volume 23'
    ,'Alan Ford - Volume 11 - Il Numero Uno'
    ,'Alan Ford - Volume 12 - La Triste Storia Di Un Giovane Ricco'
    ,'Alan Ford - Volume 13 - Golf'
)
foreach ($Dir in $Dirs) {
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path $Dir)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Dir | Out-Null }
}

# Code to move files starts here vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
(Get-ChildItem -Directory -Filter '* - Volume*').Name |
    ForEach-Object {
        $NewDirName = $_.Split(' - ')[0]
        if (-not (Test-Path -Path $NewDirName)) { New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $NewDirName | Out-Null }
        Move-Item -Path $_ -Destination $NewDirName
    }
# Code to move files ends here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: your code is good but it split filename, for example if I have a foldername like `Alan Ford - Volume 11 - Il Numero Uno` your script moves folders creating a parent folder name as `Alan` and not `Alan Ford`.- is there a fix for this?

Comment: @AlexDoc, that is not what happened on my machine. It created an `Alan Ford` directory. What version of PowerShell are you using? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()` produces `7.1.0-preview.3`. I do get the failed result on `5.1.19041.868`. Any change you could get on a more current version?

Comment: yes, now it works, I follow your tip and I update Powershell version. Really thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished fairly simple in Powershell. Using `Get-ChildItem` to enumerate through directories, we can filter for specific key words and then pipe them to another cmdlet.

```
#Filter for directories with the word "volume"  in it
#Then pipe to a Foreach-Object loop to have it perform the same action 
#over for the objects passed to it
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\some\path -Filter "*volume*" -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Process { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination C:\Some\OtherFolder }
```

Depending on your Posh Version as well, you can add a `-Directory` Parameter to just list directories and ignore files. I haven't really looked into `Move-Item` cmdlet but, this should work.

Per your comment:

```
$Folder    = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Some\Path -Filter "*volume*" -Directory -Recurse #| ForEach-Object -Process { Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination C:\Some\OtherFolder }
$Folder1   = $Folder.FullName.split('\')[-1]
$newFolder =  "$($Folder1.Split(' ')[0])" + " $($Folder1.Split(' ')[1])"
If(-not (Test-Path -Path C:\Some\Path\$newFolder)){
    New-Item -Path C:\some\path -Name $newFolder -ItemType Directory -OutVariable Location
    }

    
Foreach($Directory in $Folder.FullName){
    Move-Item -Path $Directory -Destination $Location.FullName}
```

Comment: you forgot to make the new directory when it doesn't exist

Comment: Didn't answer what wasnt asked(: but, thats just as easy.

Comment: I try to use your script but simply move folders from a folder to another.  Can you also add new directory when it doesn't exist? For example, what name creates if names are `Absolute Moebius - Volume 3` / `Absolute Moebius - Volume 4`? Absolute Moebius?

Comment: a lil more scripting but, its doable; see edit.

Comment: Please note, this is off top of my head and hasnt been tested. Should work(:

Comment: @AbrahamZinala it works but only for one single folder group. For example if I have from source path one folder group like `Alan Ford - Volume1` / `Alan Ford - Volume 2` your script it works ==> it moves correctly inside Alan Ford folder. But if in same source path I have more than one group of folders, for example if i have another folder group like  `Zaira - Volume 10` / 
`Zaira - Volume 20` your script move all folders in Alan Ford folder group also Zaira folders who does not belong to that group.

Comment: The code that you need is there, I encourage you to try it yourself:) id just be writing everything myself without you actually learning something.